# What's the point of implementing onItemClick function in MainActivity for Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I found that people create a customized listener interface(which only has one onListItemClick function) for the `RecyclerView`'s adapter and then implement the listener's `onListItemClick` function in the `MainActivity` class. Eventually, the `MainActivity` is passed to the adapter constructor to use the `onListItemClick` for its view holders. Why should we do that in the `MainActivity` class instead of just do it in the adapter or view hodler class?
An example of this can be found on the link:
https://github.com/udacity/ud851-Exercises/compare/T03.07-Exercise-RecyclerViewClickHandling...T03.07-Solution-RecyclerViewClickHandling

Comment: The MainActivity is not passed (or at least shouldn't be), the interface implementation is. You aren't required to implement an interface on the Activity, it's just "cleaner" (lookup Callback hell)

Answer (score 1):

Using the interface is necessary when using a `RecyclerView`, because unlike`ListView` you cannot simply use `setOnItemClickListener()` directly on `RecyclerView` to operate on an individual list item.

Because of the dynamic and "recycling" nature of `RecyclerView`, any `onClickListener()` must be applied to the view of the `ViewHolder` inside the adapter.

This means that using an interface to communicate between the activity and the adapter is what must be done.